# Download file smaller than it's real size

Tags: python-3.6

I'm trying to download all the comics(png) from xkcd.com and here's my code to do the download job:

```
imageFile=open(os.path.join('XKCD',os.path.basename(comicLink)),'wb')
        for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
            imageFile.write(chunk)
        imageFile.close()
```

And the downloadeded file is 6388Bytes and cannot be opened while the real file from link is 27.6Kb.

I've already tested my code line by line in shell, so I'm pretty sure I get the right link and right file.
I just don't understand why the png downloaded by my code is smaller.
Also I tried to search why this is happening but without helpful information.
Thanks.

Comment: How is res initialised? Is it from the result of an http request?

Comment: @Colwin will it be?  I checked it with raise_for_status() and it works

Comment: Are you using urllib or requests to actually connect to the server and download the image?

Comment: @Colwin I'm using requests. And I think res.raise_for_status() should do checking the connect. If it's not, I had to admit I'm really fresh to python.  If it's needed I could paste more of my code up FYI. Many thanks again.

Comment: it turned out I've got a really stupid mistake that I forgot to add "http://" in front of the download Url.XD

Comment: It happens! We've all made stupid mistakes, that how you learn. :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay since you are using requests here is function that will let you download a file given a url

```
def download_file(url):
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    # NOTE the stream=True parameter
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)

    return local_filename
```

Link to the documentation -> http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow